# I Want to Group IDs According to Eco_Status Using R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want another data frame that has the four(4) `Eco_Status` as column and group each `ID` as each occurs under each `Eco_Status`

```
# group ID_numbers according to their respective status
df <- read.table(text =
                   "ID Pof_Exp  Eco_Status Gender
              31304  2  poor male
              31310  4  poor female
              31307  6  rich male
              31302  8  average male
              31301 10 billionaire male
              31308  2  poor female
              31316  4  poor male
              31317  6  rich male
              31312  8  average female
              31306 10 average female
              31314  2  poor female
              31311  4  average male
              31305  6  rich male
              31303  8  average male
              31309 10  average female
              31324  2  poor male
              31320  4  poor female
              31327  6  average male
              31322  8  average female
              31321 10 billionaire    male",
              header = TRUE)
```

Given the above data frame `df`, I want a `vector` of `ID` having `poor`, `average`, `rich`, and `billionaire` as their status.

Comment: `split(df$ID, df$Eco_Status)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is another possible solution:

```
df %>% select(-c(Pof_Exp, Gender)) %>% group_by(Eco_Status) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Eco_Status, values_from = ID) %>% 
  select(-row)
```

which gives:

```
poor  rich average billionaire
  <int> <int>   <int>       <int>
1 31304 31307   31302       31301
2 31310 31317   31312       31321
3 31308 31305   31306          NA
4 31316    NA   31311          NA
5 31314    NA   31303          NA
6 31324    NA   31309          NA
7 31320    NA   31327          NA
8    NA    NA   31322          NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
df %>%
    group_by(Eco_Status) %>%
    summarise(ID = list(ID))

   Eco_Status                                                     ID
1     average 31302, 31312, 31306, 31311, 31303, 31309, 31327, 31322
2 billionaire                                           31301, 31321
3        poor        31304, 31310, 31308, 31316, 31314, 31324, 31320
4        rich                                    31307, 31317, 31305
```

Comment: This is what I got from your solution, which is different from what you print. `# A tibble: 4 × 2
  Eco_Status  ID       
  <chr>       <list>   
1 average     <int [8]>
2 billionaire <int [2]>
3 poor        <int [7]>
4 rich        <int [3]>` I suspect some required packages are not revealed in your answer.

Comment: trying `View`ing the dataframe afterwards @DanielJames

Comment: or turning it into a dataframe, from a tibble